# Should I upgrade dragons or baby dragons?

Tags: clash-of-clans

The cost is the same and I'm wondering if I should first research to upgrade baby dragons to level 2 or upgrade normal dragons to level 4? I've used dragons more than baby dragons, but this doesn't mean much as baby dragons are a lot newer, and all dragon attacks are not practiced after town hall 7 anyways. I'm town hall 9 right now. I know it's true for buildings, but do troop upgrades have more of a benefit in lower levels? For example is the difference between 1-2 greater than the difference between 3-4?

Comment: This is completely subjective. Upgrade whichever one you use more. I never use dragons, and I only use baby dragons for clan castle defense. What do you use?

Comment: @Ellesedil I already explained that due to the simple fact that I only just acquired baby dragons, I don't use them as much. Also, what do you mean you use baby dragons as town hall defense? While this affects your clan members, it has no affect on your own game.

Comment: I don't know why this question is so downvoted. This is a legitimate one, far from being only subjective. The OP has a definite problem that can be solved by some piece of advice, it is not just : "_Should I buy black shoes, or white ones ?_".

Comment: @Ksyqo for some reason people on this site think questions regarding strategy are bad or off topic.

Comment: @Ksyqo Question legitimacy has no relevance here at Arqade.  There's lots of legit questions that we won't help with that all.  It's all about question usefulness.  We don't like questions that are generally opinionated, and that's what this one seems to be.  There could be some decent answers to it, but I don't know enough about Clash of Clans to be sure.

Comment: @Frank totally agreed. This question seems like an opinionated one, but it's actually not. It's "legitimate" in the sense that it is a relevant and useful question.

Comment: @Ksyqo Is it?  It certainly doesn't seem so.  The community definitely doesn't think so right now.  It seems more like a, "Which one should I use?" question, which is generally up to individual playstyle, and the specific situation they're in.

Comment: @Celeritas They flagged it because some people might prefer upgrading Dragons, while others might want Baby Dragons.

Comment: @John yes but they can explain their reasoning. I think it's ridiculous to say you're not allowed to talk about strategy when the game IS a strategy game.

Comment: If you want to reopen this question, it might be worth trying to narrow the situation. You haven't specified anything beyond unit A or B. If you provide a scenario of some sort, that might eliminate enough of the opinionated section to make it worthwhile.

Comment: Although using your baby dragons for defence does not directly influence your own game play, it _does_ influence your clan mates, and thus also your own clan. In clan wars, this can have big impact on defences, and so also the difference between defeat and victory in a war. You might care about that difference in war loot bonus...

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer** : the following answer is my humble opinion based on my experience and my knowledge, and does not pretend to reveal the absolute truth on what you should or should not do. If you like full-dragons raids, you'd do better to update your dragons.

### Upgrade your baby dragons.

You're right to say that dragons are pretty inefficient after th7/8. Actually, when you reach th9, you (and I, and almost everyone) usually don't use them at all, because it's simply not powerful enough.

**Baby dragons are really nice when put in a clan castle**. Put one in a castle and it will be **[enraged](https://clashofclans.com/clash-basics/troops/baby-dragon)**, doubling its attack speed (i.e. doubling the damage). This is one of the most strategic use of the clan castle during clan wars.

In a more general way, see the most effective use of baby dragons as their enraged state. Include some of those in a grounded-troops team composition (giants, walkyries, wizards, golems...), spread them around the map so they can be enraged. If you upgrade them, you *double* the value of the additional attack given by the upgrade. That makes it really worth the 5.000.000 elixir you invest in.

Again, this is only my opinion based on my experience and what I've tested. If your playstyle goes around dragons, you should definitively focus on them.